# How to use react-datepicker with redux form?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, redux-form

I'm trying to make react datepicker works with redux-form, I've already read my answers on stackoverflow I made the picker works fine but I can't type anything on the field for some reason. It's interesting that if I try to paste a valid date like 12/30/2019, then it also works. Here is my code

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import moment from "moment";

const RenderDatePicker = ({ input }) => (
  <div>
    <DatePicker
      {...input}
      className="form-control"
      onChange={date => input.onChange(moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))}
      selected={input.value ? moment(input.value, "MM/DD/YYYY") : null}
    />
  </div>
);

const SimpleForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name={"datePicker"} component={RenderDatePicker} />

      <button type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "simple"
})(SimpleForm);
```

Comment: try this reference -> https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/543

Answer (score 2):

What I did was create a separated `Datepicker` component

```
export const FieldDatePicker = ({ input, placeholder, minDate, maxDate }) => (
    <DatePicker
        className="plus-icon"
        dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
        selected={input.value || null}
        onChange={input.onChange}
        minDate={minDate}
        maxDate={maxDate}
        disabledKeyboardNavigation
        placeholderText={placeholder}
    />
);
```

and then use it from `<Field />`

```
<Field
    component={FieldDatePicker}
    name="date_till"
    placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
const RenderDatePicker = ({input}) => {
const inputWrap = (
    <div>
     <DatePicker
      {...input}
      className="form-control"
      onChange={date => input.onChange(moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))}
      selected={input.value ? moment(input.value, "MM/DD/YYYY") : null}
    />

return (
    <div>
        {inputWrap}
    </div>
);
```

};